# Could not connect to SQL Server using osql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a script that connects to SQL Server 2005 default instance. But I'm and being connected and instead got the following message

```
[SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
[SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
[SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
```

The script's content is:

```
osql -E -S <servername> -i D:\scripts\script1.sql -o D:\scripts\script1.txt
```

I looked at the network connection from SQL Server Configuration Manager. The TCP/IP is enabled but the Named Pipes is disabled.

My question is what could be the possible cause and solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try osql -E -S(local) or osql -E -S.  I have not figured out why sometimes it does work, and other times it does not.